# Deriving sum of dependent events

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

I'm trying to derive formula for dependents events.

Let say we have a box with 5 balls: 2 whites and 3 red. Calculate the probability of:

- get white first, then red
- OR get red first, then white

As I understand, we should use formula P(A + B), where:

- event A: get white ball
- event B: get red ball
- event (B|A): get red ball if white already taken
- event (A|B): get white ball if red already taken

So, following events can happen:

$${\above 0pt A * (B|A)}$$
$${\above 0pt B * (A|B)}$$
$${{\above 0pt A \space * }{ \above 1pt {(B|A)}}}$$
$${{\above 0pt B \space * }{ \above 1pt {(A|B)}}}$$

Therefore:

$${P(A + B) =  P(A) * P(B|A) + P(B) * P(A|B) + P(A) * (1 - P(B|A)) + P(B) * (1 - P(A|B))}$$
$${ = 2 * P(A) * P(B|A) + P(A) - P(A) * P(B|A) + P(B) - P(B) * P(A|B)}$$
$${ = 2 * P(A) * P(B|A) + P(A) - 2 * P(A) * P(B|A) + P(B)}$$
$${ = P(A) + P(B)}$$

P(A) = 2/5
P(B) = 3/5

P(A + B) = 2/5 + 3/5 = 1

**Question:** Is it right formula and probability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $W_1$ denote the event that the first ball drawn is white.

Let $W_2$ denote the event that the second ball drawn is white.

Let $R_1$ denote the event that the first ball drawn is red.

Let $R_2$ denote the event that the second ball drawn is red.

Then to be found is: 
$$\begin{aligned}P\left(\left(W_{1}\cap R_{2}\right)\cup\left(R_{1}\cap W_{2}\right)\right) & =P\left(W_{1}\cap R_{2}\right)+P\left(R_{1}\cap W_{2}\right)\\
 & =P\left(R_{2}\mid W_{1}\right)P\left(W_{1}\right)+P\left(W_{2}\mid R_{1}\right)P\left(R_{1}\right)\\
 & =\frac{3}{9}\frac{2}{10}+\frac{2}{9}\frac{3}{10}\\
 & =\frac{2}{15}
\end{aligned}
$$

Now check yourself.

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation! One more question: does it mean that we don't have any predefined formula for dependents events ?

Comment: Do you mean the events that you denoted as $(B|A)$ and $(A\mid B)$? If so then actually that are no events at all, because they cannot be recognized as elements of $\mathcal A$ (preassuming that we work with some probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal A,P)$). At most you could call them "conditional events". In my view they are confusing, and we certainly do not need them. In my answer I write e.g. $P(R_2\mid W_1)$ but $(R_2\mid W_1)$ is not really an event, i.e. element of $\mathcal A$.

Answer (score 0):

When you draw two balls, there are four outcomes:
$$P(W_1\cap W_2)=P(W_1)\cdot P(W_2|W_1)=\frac25\cdot \frac14=\frac{1}{10};$$
$$P(W_1\cap R_2)=\frac25\cdot \frac34=\frac{3}{10};$$
$$P(R_1\cap W_2)=\frac35\cdot \frac24=\frac{3}{10};$$
$$P(R_1\cap R_2)=\frac35\cdot \frac24=\frac{3}{10}.$$
And you want to find:
$$P((W_1\cap R_2)\cup (R_1\cap W_2))=P(W_1\cap R_2)+P(R_1\cap W_2).$$